# use data-key of item in ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'd like to set a `data-key` in my HTML, in this case `myKey` and use this to check whether `myObject[data-key] == true`. If it is then the field should be disabled.

```
$scope.myObject = {
  myKey : true
}

<input type='text' ng-model='x' name="x" id="x" data-key="myKey" ng-disabled="myObject[data-key]"/>
```

If I simply do this it works...

```
<input type='text' ng-model='x' name="x" id="x" data-key="myKey" ng-disabled="myObject.myKey == true"/>
```

But I'd like to be able to pass in data-key rather than the string. Is this possible?

[Plunk here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bCuUfCsr1rIKfVvYYsy1?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an custom directive something like

```
app.directive('myDir', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
        myKey:'=',
        object:'='
        }, 
        link: function(scope, $elm, $attrs) {
          console.log(scope.myKey); 
          if(scope.object[scope.myKey])
             scope.isDisabled=true;
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

[Working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/25BLKWjLAKr9rmg1Bqbn?p=preview)

Comment: Nice idea, i'll give it a go. Thanks

Comment: Ok you can change `$scope.myKey=` value in controller to see the effect